# MonoMac Signing with "codesign" for Mac Store. (Invalid Binary)

Tags: macos, store, app-store-connect, codesign, monomac

Hi im trying to code sign a MonoMac binary for the Mac Store via "Application Loader".  I can submit the app, but the status in "Itunes Connect" will always say "Invalid Binary" !?  The reason I have to manually do this is because theres a bug in MonoMac signing.  But i'm starting to pull my hair out now as it been over a day and a half.

I also get back an email saying:

> Invalid Signature - the main app bundle Paper Tanks at path Paper
>   Tanks.app is signed but the signature is invalid.

If I try to sign the binary with this the "Application Loader" will give an error:

```
codesign -v --force --sign "A72F25F56B7D6C43332AE795288EA092009BE737" "--resource-rules=/Users/Andrew/Reign/Games/papertanks/PaperTanks_OSX/PaperTanks_OSX/bin/AppStore/Paper Tanks.app/Contents/Resources/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Users/Andrew/Reign/Games/papertanks/PaperTanks_OSX/PaperTanks_OSX/bin/AppStore/Paper Tanks.xcent" "/Users/Andrew/Reign/Games/papertanks/PaperTanks_OSX/PaperTanks_OSX/bin/AppStore/Paper Tanks.app"

Application Loader error = "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'com.apple.application-indetifier' in Paper Tanks.app/Contents/macOS/Paper Tanks'."
```

So because the step above fails I then code sign the app like this:

> codesign -v --force --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Application:
>   Andrew Witte" "--resource-rules=.../AppStore/Paper
>   Tanks.app/Contents/Resources/ResourceRules.plist" "..../AppStore/Paper
>   Tanks.app"

Then I code sign the internal mono posix lib as the last step doesn't seem to.

> codesign -v --force --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Application:
>   Andrew Witte" .../AppStore/Paper\
>   Tanks.app/Contents/Resources/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib

Then I build and sign the pkg:

> productbuild --component ".../AppStore/Paper Tanks.app" /Applications
>   --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Andrew Witte" ".../AppStore/PaperTanks_OSX-0.1.pkg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was fixed by me upgrading to Xcode 4.4